# To omit ‘one’ or not

Tags: sentence-construction, pronouns

> 1. Are the pixels of a 1080p 43-inch screen bigger than a 1080p 32-inch **one**?

Should I keep the ‘one’ or remove and write:

> 2. Are the pixels of a 1080p 43-inch screen bigger than a 1080p 32-inch?

So, 1 or 2, which one sounds better? Or should I repeat the ‘screen’, like:

> 3. Are the pixels of a 1080p 43-inch screen bigger than a 1080p 32-inch "screen"?

Answer (score 1):

For a formal written version I would say:

> Are the pixels of a 1080p 43-inch screen bigger than those of a 1080p 32-inch screen?

In speech, I would drop the "one", and can imagine this being said as:

> Does a 1080p 43-inch screen have bigger pixels than a 1080p 32-inch?

The "32-inch" effectively becomes a sort of alias for the product type, and it's quite common to hear things like this with sizes, etc.

Comment: In the formal version, is that subject ‘those’ a pronoun of ‘pixels’?

Comment: Yes, "those" could effectively be replaced with "the pixels".

Comment: Agreed you can use “one” instead of “screen” or omit both.  But here’s another example where you can’t omit the noun or “one(s)”: “Are the green tea KitKats more expensive than the regular chocolate ones?”

Comment: @OrbitalAussie: You could actually say do this by saying: “Are green tea KitKats more expensive than regular chocolate?” Notice that you don't need the word "the" at all in this sentence.

Comment: @ChrisMack. You could, but I see this as a bit ambiguous because “regular chocolate” sounds like you might mean a regular block of chocolate etc.

Comment: @OrbitalAussie: I suppose this is a little ambiguous, however, it would likely be understood in the context, and is quite idiomatic - it's also unlikely that you would say "regular chocolate" to refer to a generic chocolate bar.

Comment: @ChrisMack: Agreed. I think it’s only other more complex statements where “ones” can’t sensibly be left out. For example you couldn’t omit it here: “The transmitter offerings seemed to be the same old things. There were small solid-state ones, ones with a big tube-type device, ones with several big tube-type devices and so on.”